# Validation loss rising before falling again

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I've been getting some strange behaviour on my training losses, and I don't know what's causing it. Axes are loss vs epochs.

[image]

There are two things going on here : first, the validation loss starts coming down nicely with the training loss, and then they begin to diverge strongly. I'm assuming this is some form of overfitting, even though the validation loss comes back down at a later point - is that correct ?

Then, the validation loss comes back down to meet the training loss - here, it coincided with a huge spike in training loss.

Does anyone have any insight into what's causing this, and what can be done to ensure things go downwards and do so smoothly ?

This was obtained using the Adam optimiser, in this case on a convolutional autoencoder, but I've also had this on an LSTM.

Comment: What is your x-axis?

Comment: Apologies. Edited to say that the x-axis is the number of epochs.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. it might be a noise in your data, your network is over fitting training set before converging. try to check your data and your regularization

Comment: I've trained it further and edited the image above. I don't think it's going to converge...

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experiences on unbalanced datasets, where the model tended to produce only 1 class output. Then it inversed the decision boundary and the performance was abysmal for a single epoch. I suggest to look at irregularities in the dataset. This could be said a balancing between the samples in each class or it could be that the ground truth is improperly set.

Anyways it is hard to accurately judge what is going wrong without knowing the use-case and/or the data.

Comment: Thanks. There are no balance issues here that I can think of - this is an image segmentation problem through a convolutional encoder-decoder. However, there's very little data, so perhaps that's causing this. On smaller networks, this looked to converge better.